# Partial derivative in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm following a proof where they define in polar coordinates

$$\ v(r, \theta) = a(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) 
\quad\text{where}\quad a \in C^\infty(B, \Bbb R)$$

Then we have

$$\ v_r = a_x\cos\theta + a_y\sin\theta,$$
$$\ v_\theta = -a_xr\sin\theta + a_yr\cos\theta$$

I'm not sure how we got here. What I got was

$$\ v_r =  (a_rr\cos\theta + a\cos\theta, a_rr\sin\theta + a\sin\theta)$$ by chain rule.

With $$\ a_r = a_xx_r + a_yy_r = a_x\cos\theta + a_y\sin\theta $$

So I end up with a vector valued function while they have a scalar. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is $a$ a function of $r$, $\theta$, or something?

Comment: a is a function of $\ x, y$

Comment: Are $r$ and $\theta$ functions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Why you have $r$ in that $\frac{dx}{dr}$, the chain rule. it should be $a_x cos \theta + a_y sin \theta$

Comment: I believe so. It's not explicitly stated but I interpret r to be euclidian distance from the origin and theta to be angle from positive real axis.

Comment: Sorry @Cardinal, not sure what you mean by your last comment. Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: I am saying your interpretation is wrong. $$  \frac{d a}{dr} = \frac{d a}{ dx} \times \frac{d x}{dr} + \frac{d a}{dy} \times \frac{d y}{ dr} $$

$$ x = r cos \theta  / / \text{and} / / y = r sin \theta $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unclear what you mean by
$$\ v_r =  (a_rr\cos\theta + a\cos\theta, a_rr\sin\theta + a\sin\theta)$$
There is a red flag here as the left hand side is a scalar, and the right hand side is not. Hopefully the following makes more sense to you.

If we take the derivative with respect to $r$ of$$v(r, \theta) = a(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$$
On the left side we clearly get $v_r$, and on the right side, if we call the partial derivatives of $a(x,y)$, $a_x$ and $a_y$, we get by the chain rule
$$\frac{d a}{dr} = \frac{d a}{ dx} \cdot \frac{d x}{dr} + \frac{d a}{dy} \cdot \frac{d y}{ dr}$$
$$v_r =a_x \cdot\left(\frac{d}{dr}r\cos\theta\right) +a_y \cdot\left(\frac{d}{dr} r\sin\theta\right) = a_x\cos\theta+a_y\sin\theta$$

Comment: In the second last line you define $\frac{d a}{dr} $, but in the last line you write $\ v_r $. Shouldn't this actually be $\ a_r $?

Comment: I understand now. Your working with @Nick Terziev's comment has explained it for me.

Comment: You probably don't need this as you say you understand now, but I did mean to write $v_r$, as since $v=a$, $v_r=a_r$

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment due to low reputation, so, I'll write this as an answer.

What they did was just writing arguments of the function explicitly in brackets.

Let's follow the example $v(r, \theta) = r \cos (\theta)$. When you change your basis to $x = r \cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta)$, you get a new function $a(x, y)= a(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) = x$. Then you shall just use the formulae for $x_r$, $x_\theta$, $y_r$, $y_\theta$, which you seem to know.

Comment: I understand. He wrote the arguments of the function out while I thought it was a multiplication. Thank you very much.